# Error: ‘CurByte’ was not declared in this scope in LLVM 15.0.2?

Tags: llvm

In path
**llvm/lib/Target/X86/MCTargetDesc/X86MCCodeEmitter.cpp**

In LLVM 9.0.0 the code is, **STI.setByteCtr(CurByte);**

But in LLVM 15.0.2 The CurByte has been replaced. In some instances the ***CurByte*** parameter is totally omitted and in some it has been replaced with StartByte
So what should be the equivalent command in case of LLVM 15.0.2?

```
  if ((TSFlags & X86II::OpMapMask) == X86II::ThreeDNow)
    EmitByte(X86II::getBaseOpcodeFor(TSFlags), CurByte, OS);

#ifndef NDEBUG
  // FIXME: Verify.
  if (/*!Desc.isVariadic() &&*/ CurOp != NumOps) {
    errs() << "Cannot encode all operands of: ";
    MI.dump();
    errs() << '\n';
    abort();
  }
#endif

  // Koo: Update the actual bytes to be emitted in MCSubtargetInfo class
  STI.setByteCtr(CurByte);
```

The equivalent portion in LLVM 15.0.2

```
  if ((TSFlags & X86II::OpMapMask) == X86II::ThreeDNow)
    emitByte(X86II::getBaseOpcodeFor(TSFlags), OS);

  assert(OS.tell() - StartByte <= 15 &&
         "The size of instruction must be no longer than 15.");
#ifndef NDEBUG
  // FIXME: Verify.
  if (/*!Desc.isVariadic() &&*/ CurOp != NumOps) {
    errs() << "Cannot encode all operands of: ";
    MI.dump();
    errs() << '\n';
    abort();
  }
#endif

  // Koo: Update the actual bytes to be emitted in MCSubtargetInfo class
  STI.setByteCtr(CurByte);


}
```